# Are you likely to be asked for medical travel insurance when visiting Israel as a Russian citizen?

Tags: visas, borders, insurance, israel, russian-citizens

I'm going to visit Israel for a couple of days. I am a Russian citizen and don't need to get a visa. How high is the probability that I'll be requested to show any kind of medical travel insurance?

This isn't a big deal: I can get it pretty easily, after all. It's just that it takes time.

Comment: Haven't been asked to present one in my visits to Israel to date.  but then again I am not a Russian citizen.

Comment: @Karlson if you country is one of those countries citizens of which are not required to obtain visa, it's most probably relevant. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's one of those things. On a busy day, the immigration official isn't going to ask you to show everything. If they're worried about you, they may press. Their concern is to make sure you're fully and legally prepared for your trip.

So if you have all your tickets ready, your passport at hand, and papers, accommodation and travel plans printed out, you'll look organised and probably won't get too many additional questions.

However, it could be that one day where they're focusing on insurance.  It's impossible to know for sure.